# Linux DMA from User Space Bus Error

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, xilinx, dma

i'm following this framework https://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/attachments/xlnx/ELINUX/10693/1/Linux%20DMA%20from%20User%20Space-public.pdf to perform a data transmission using a DMA. I'm using AXI DMA without 
scatter gather, with the transmit stream looped back to the receive 
stream. The codes i am using are the following:[dma_proxy.c](https://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/attachments/xlnx/ELINUX/11603/1/dma_proxy.c), 
[dma_proxy.h](https://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/attachments/xlnx/ELINUX/11603/2/dma_proxy.h), [dma_proxy_test.c](https://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/attachments/xlnx/ELINUX/11603/3/dma_proxy_test.c).
I have trying to change the u32 for u64 as i'm worknig in a 64bits system. 
The dma_proxy kernel module works correctly and performs the INTERNAL_TEST correctly, but when i try to read/write on the dma buffers after mapping them on the user application i get this error:

```
DMA proxy test
[  397.889331] Unhandled fault: level 3 address size fault (0x92000043) at 0x0000007f94d4b004
Bus error
```

In addtition according to the framework i should watch the DMA buffers on Kernel Mapping Area when i export kernel pagetable, but i get it on  vmalloc() Area :

```
0xffffff80012c5000-0xffffff80012cd000          32K     RW NX SHD AF            UXN MEM/NORMAL-NC
0xffffff80012ce000-0xffffff80015cf000        3076K     RW NX SHD AF            UXN MEM/NORMAL-NC
0xffffff80015d0000-0xffffff80015d8000          32K     RW NX SHD AF            UXN MEM/NORMAL-NC
0xffffff80015d9000-0xffffff80018da000        3076K     RW NX SHD AF            UXN MEM/NORMAL-NC
```

The files are from this post : https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/BRAM-DMA-transfer-limitation/m-p/555953#M11603
I'm running on a zcu102 evaluation board from Xilinx (Zynq Ultrascale+).

Any idea??

Comment: Did you try a standalone application (with SDK) just to verify that the HW works properly?( Something simple like read/write array)

Comment: As i said, internal test of dma_proxy works correctly, so the HW works properly as i can perform transfers on the kernel space. The problem occurs when i try to perform the transfer mapping the buffers on the user space.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve my problem with help from Xilinx Suppornt. It’s the driver code mmap function which make use of dma_common_mmap rather than dma_mmap_coherent, which is the one that should be used to mmap the memory areas allocated by the dmam_alloc_coherent.